# Projeto para iPad e iPhone

Tags: ios, iphone, storyboard

Bom, estou com um problema, estou com um projeto onde tenho um arquivo `Storyboard` para iPhone e outro arquivo `Storyboard` para iPad. Então tenho uma `UIImageView` no Storyboard para iPhone, e outro `UIImageView` no Storyboard do iPad.

Mas tenho um `IBOutlet` já conectado e recebendo imagens e exibindo as imagens no simulador usando o iPhone. Mas ainda não conectei a `UIImageView` do iPad pois estou em duvida, se **tem como conectar no mesmo IBOutlet do iPhone**, ou teria que criar outro `ViewController` so para o iPad.

Alguem poderia me ajudar?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Não, nao precisa criar outro ViewController para iPad; você pode usar o mesmo para ambos. O IBOutlet pode receber duas ligações, uma pra iPhone e outra pra iPad. 
Entretanto, certifique-se de que a View que você tem no iPad está referenciada a sua ViewController (file owner)!

Comment: Vou dar uma olhada!! Obrigado